# R dendextend set "leaves_col" converts leaves pch to character

Tags: r, dendextend

I am creating a dendrogram using dendextend and wish to set leaves as colored symbols.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(dendextend)

sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dendextend_0.18.3 ggplot2_1.0.1
```

Make a simple dendrogram

```
data(USArrests)

dend = USArrests[1:5,] %>% 
    scale %>%
    dist %>% 
    hclust %>% 
    as.dendrogram
```

Setting leaves_pch works fine

```
dend1 = dend %>%
    set("leaves_pch", 19)

get_leaves_attr(dend1, "nodePar", simplify=T)
  pch pch pch pch pch 
   19  19  19  19  19
```

Plots as expected

```
plot(dend1)
```

[image: dendrogram with leaves pch=19]

But when I add colors the pch values convert to character

```
dend2 = dend %>%
    set("leaves_pch", 19) %>%
    set("leaves_col", "blue")


get_leaves_attr(dend2, "nodePar", simplify=T)
   pch    col    pch    col    pch    col    pch    col    pch    col 
  "19" "blue"   "19" "blue"   "19" "blue"   "19" "blue"   "19" "blue"
```

Causing problems with plotting

```
plot(dend2)
```

[image: dendrogram with leaves pch converted to characters]

Is there a workaround? I'm sure I'm missing something simple...

Comment: I can confirm that when I run your code, it plots in the fashion you're looking for (i.e. with blue circles as the leaves).  I'd try reinstalling `dendextend` and maybe updating `R` if possible.

Comment: Finally got around to updating to the latest ggplot2 and that seems to fix. Thanks!

Comment: Just to say that this has nothing to do with ggplot2, but it could be a bug from earlier version of dendextend. In the current version, it seems to be resolved. Thanks.